# Does anybody know how to link against `ld` on `WSL`?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dynamic-linking

I'm compiling a test program on clion using windows subsystem for linux `WSL`. I am using `dlopen` etc. to load a library at runtime. The error I am getting is:

```
CMakeFiles/test.dir/test_add.cpp.o: In function `test_test_add_windows_Test::TestBody()':
/mnt/d/ACrossPlatformCppLibrary/test/test_add.cpp:26: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/mnt/d/ACrossPlatformCppLibrary/test/test_add.cpp:28: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

[Reports](https://gist.github.com/kwk/3595733) seem to suggest that I need to link against `ld`. However, adding

`target_link_libraries(ACrossPlatformCppLibrary "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")`

Doesn't work, which is no suprise because it looks like `"${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}"` is empty on windows. So I tried to manually give the path to `ld`

`target_link_libraries(ACrossPlatformCppLibrary "/usr/bin/ld")`

Does anybody know how to link against `ld` on `WSL`?

## update

Thanks to comments and the answer by @squareskittles, I've noticed that the `dl` binary is not available on the system path. On closer inspection, it doesn't look like the `dl` binary exists at all in `WSL`. Here is a cut and paste of the directory I think `dl` should be in:

```
$ cd /lib
$ ls
apparmor       hdparm                                libhandle.so.1.0.3  netplan        udev
console-setup  init                                  lsb                 open-iscsi     ufw
cpp            klibc-wBFLvVtxy4xJqEadIBJMa78iJz8.so  modprobe.d          recovery-mode  x86_64-linux-gnu
cryptsetup     **ld-linux.so.2**                         modules             systemd
ebtables       libhandle.so.1                        modules-load.d      terminfo
```

Comment: better to links against so not executable. `target_link_libraries(TARGET PRIVATE ld)` should work

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error using `target_link_libraries(TARGET PRIVATE ld)`

Comment: The `libdl.so` library should be located in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory, which it appears you have. Updating my response with this info.

Comment: Dependig on the Linux-distribution you've installed into your WSL, you have to install a package called `libc-devel` or `glibc-dev` or something like that: that package contains a file called `libdl.so` (though it is just a symlink to `libdl.so.someversion`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the GNU link library flag `-l` with the library name `dl`, which together in the link stage appear as `-ldl`. If the library is in the system path (of WSL), you should not need the full path to the library either. You can simply put the library name `dl` in this command:

```
 target_link_libraries(ACrossPlatformCppLibrary PRIVATE dl)
```

For what it's worth, the `libdl.so` library on WSL should be located here if you have the proper packages installed:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```